# link libraries to run dwarf fortress

Tags: linux, shared-libraries

I want to go into the world of dwarf fortress, however I found a problem linking the libraries needed to run the game. It gives me

```
error while loading shared libraries: libSDL-1.2.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

maybe I will need the 32bit version of the libraries, but I don't want to make a mess merging 64libs and 32libs.

Is it safe to do it without causing damage?

Which libraries do I need?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit)

Comment: This might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/226613/how-do-i-run-dwarf-fortress/421820#421820